# only get json objects with a matching key

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

So what I want to do is rather simple. I have a site where comments are displayed, and I have an admin page that allows an admin to delete comments. However I need comments to be hidden before they are reviewed.

This script grabs each object in my json file and displays them:

```
    $.getJSON("data/comments.json", function(data) {
    var number = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, d) {
        number.push("<div class='comment' id='" + index + "'>" + "<div class='comment-text'>" + d.comment + "</div>" + "<img class='comment-image' src='data/upload/" + d.img + "'>" + "<div class='comment-identifier'><span class='comment-name'>" + "– " + d.name + "</span>" + "<span class='comment-department'>" + ", " + d.department + "</span></div>" + "</div>");
    });
    $("<div/>", {
        "id": "comment-container",
        html: number.join("")
    }).appendTo("#comment-layout");
});
```

Each json object will have a key of "approved: false" applied to it upon creation. How can I have the above script only pull objects with a  "approved: true" on them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check if the comment is approved or not in the `$.each` function.

```
$.each(data, function(index, d) {
   if(d.approved){
        number.push("<div class='comment' id='" + index + "'>" + "<div class='comment-text'>" + d.comment + "</div>" + "<img class='comment-image' src='data/upload/" + d.img + "'>" + "<div class='comment-identifier'><span class='comment-name'>" + "– " + d.name + "</span>" + "<span class='comment-department'>" + ", " + d.department + "</span></div>" + "</div>");
   }
});
```

Comment: Ah that seems simple, wasn't sure if I needed a $.grep or what. I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that `d.approved` is stored as boolean and not as string (in that case use `d.approved == "true"`). Also as @EoiFirst said, the data will still be available on the client side and may be inspected using Developer Tools (or similar)

Comment: Yeah I'm not worried about someone poking around and seeing it, it's an internal project, most people aren't going to know how or care to do so. And if a comment is disapproved, it will get deleted from the server-side data file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it is approved before pushing it to your array. It doesn't prevent the data to be received client side though.

```
$.getJSON("data/comments.json", function(data) {
    var number = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, d) {

        if (d.approved == false)
           continue;

        number.push("<div class='comment' id='" + index + "'>" + "<div class='comment-text'>" + d.comment + "</div>" + "<img class='comment-image' src='data/upload/" + d.img + "'>" + "<div class='comment-identifier'><span class='comment-name'>" + "– " + d.name + "</span>" + "<span class='comment-department'>" + ", " + d.department + "</span></div>" + "</div>");
    });
    $("<div/>", {
        "id": "comment-container",
        html: number.join("")
    }).appendTo("#comment-layout");
});
```

If you don't want the data to arrive at client side, you should filter your data server side, and use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON :

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'routeToYourFilterFunction',
   success: function(data){
      number.push();
   }
});
```